Downloading file из интернета
Пишу веб-программу, по нажатию кнопки на локальную машину пользователя (вероятнее всего в папку загрузки) должен сохраняться список клиентов. Сейчас прописан абсолютный путь для сохранения файла на моем рабочем столе, как мне изменить путь таким обраом, чтоб он стал универсален для любого пользователя
 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\client_data.txt");
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter
                        (new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            List<Client> list = (List<Client>) clientRepository.findAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                writer.write(list.get(i).getId() + " " + list.get(i).getName() + " (" + list.get(i).getClStatus() + ") " + list.get(i).getGeneralNum() + ", " + list.get(i).getExtraNum1() + ", " + list.get(i).getExtraNum2() + '\n');
            }...


String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(userHome + "\\Desktop\\client_data.txt");

Таким образом должно подобрать правильный диск и пользователя.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\Desktop\\client_data.txt";
System.out.println(userHome);
    }
}

Выведет
E:\>java Main.java
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client_data.txt

